# Storyboards load VERY slowly (20-30 minutes) for all tvos projects - Any suggestions

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tvos

I had a hard crash of Xcode 7.1 (GA) yesterday while working on a tvOS project.  Since then, it is now taking 20-30 minutes for any tvOS storyboard to load -- regardless of the tvOS project I'm working on (including any new tvOS projects I create)

I've uninstalled Xcode 7.1 and then reinstalled, but the issue persists.

Any ideas on how to fix and/or work-around this issue? I suspect even when I uninstalled Xcode 7.1 and reinstalled, there's some residual files somewhere that need to be cleaned out before I do another install.  The problem is just on this one machine, other instances on other Mac's are working (reasonably) okay.

One added piece of information: when a storyboard on a new project loads, the default dark gray gradient within the initial view controller is gone.  It's now just white.

Comment: It's similar for me, when I tap on one to open, I get the beach ball. If I switch to another app and back to Xcode it usually fixes it.